# Can array index be floating in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have array in C#, and my logic is stuck and it can only work if i can have floating indexes.

Can day be 0.5 or 2.5 like that

days[day, col]=1;

Please let me know solution

Comment: no. an array index is an integer by definition.

Comment: I would like to know the reason for your question, more detailed as in your code sample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write *indexers* using any type you like, e.g.

```
public double this[double x, int y]
{
    get { ... }
    set { ... }
}
```

You can't index into an *array* by a non-integer though.

Answer (score 3):

Floats generally make terrible indexes, as it's not only possible but indeed quite common for two similar-looking floats to compare as unequal. (For instance, in most environments (`1/3` and `1-(2/3)` will give two distinct results.) Is there some reasonably small constant you can multiply your indices by to make them always integers?

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer [`Indexers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in this situation.

Use [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) keyword with your function and put these parameters.

EDIT: As Jon [`says`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6660015/can-array-index-be-floating-in-c-net/6660030#6660030); these are non-integer, you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary<> instead of array, where the key can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you actually looking for indexing of arrays of arrays aka jagged arrays? Those are indexed like this: days[day][col]. More information here:

[MSDN on Jagged Arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx)